# Как составить запрос, чтобы из одного SELECT взять массив с переменными и уже в другом SELECT использовать этот массив для другого массива?

Tags: php, sql

Есть функция, по которой надо вывести пользователей определенного саппорта.

Есть 2 таблицы.

supports_user:

```
id | support_id | client_id
1  |     2      |    10
2  |     2      |     9
3  |     2      |     8
```

users :

```
id | status |
8  |    3   |
9  |    3   |
10 |    3   |
```

Нужно из таблицы "supports_user" найти все "client_id" одного саппорта,
и положить все значения в массив $client_id.
Далее с помощью значений из этого массива найти всех пользователей из второй выборки и поместить данные уже в другой массив, который я и буду выводить.

Вот то что получилось, но не работает.

Вызываю функцию users в controller.

```
$users=users($id);
```

Сама функция в model.

```
function users($id){
global $connection;
$query = "SELECT * FROM supports_user WHERE support_id = '$id' ORDER BY id DESC ";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$client_id = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $client_id[$row['client_id']] = $row;
}

foreach($client_id as $val) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status='3' AND id = '$val' ORDER BY id DESC ";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
}
    $users = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $users[$row['id']] = $row;
    }
    return $users;}
```

А выводить это всё в шаблоне

```
<?php foreach($users as $use): ?>
```

и т.д.

Подскажите, что не так или как это сделать по другому, заранее спасибо.

Comment: вам этот ваш промежуточный массив нужен сам по себе?

Comment: нет, только для того чтобы вторую выборку сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делайте одним запросом

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u 
JOIN supports_user s ON s.client_id = u.id
WHERE u.status='3' AND s.support_id = '$id'
```

$id - переменная которую передаете в функцию users($id)

Результатом запроса будет выборка из таблицы пользователей (users)

Comment: Спасибо, вставил код, работает, но не до конца понимаю что к чему(
Где можно почитать про такое составление запросов? Если не трудно подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: `s.support_id '$id'` -> s.support_id **=** '$id'

Comment: да, я уже понял, что опечатка)

Comment: Исправил опечатку, про джоины доступно пожалуй тут написано

https://anton-pribora.ru/articles/mysql/mysql-join/

Comment: спасибо вам большое